# How to prevent duplicate element before pushing to an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I would like to ask how to do the validation (stop appending the duplicate element) before appending to the array?

```
sub create_release_text_file {

  my $result_path = shift;
  my %hshReleasebuild;
  my $json_releasebuild_array;
  my $json_releasebuild_text;

  my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;

  $hshReleasebuild{"Build"}   = $ARG_BUILD;
  $hshReleasebuild{"Release"} = $ARG_RELEASE;

  my $release_path = File::Spec->catfile($result_path, "release.txt");
  if (-e $release_path) {
    open RELEASE_FILE, "<", $release_path or die $!;
    my $json = do { local $/; <RELEASE_FILE> };
    $json_releasebuild_array = decode_json($json);
    close RELEASE_FILE;

    # print Dumper(\$json_releasebuild_array);
  }

  # Do the validation here before appending into the array

  push(@{$json_releasebuild_array}, \%hshReleasebuild);
  $json_releasebuild_text = $json->encode(\@{$json_releasebuild_array});

  open RELEASE_FILE, ">", $release_path or die $!;
  print RELEASE_FILE $json_releasebuild_text;
  close RELEASE_FILE;
```

Comment: What criteria determine whether a duplicate occurs, and what does the data in `$json_releasebuild_array` look like? Normally, the best way to check for duplication is by storing items in a hash, where the hash key is the essential thing that determines duplication and the value is the full data item. There are various question in the Perl FAQ on such topics.

Comment: $json_releasebuild_array looks like :`[
            {
              'Release' => '11.0',
              'Build' => '135'
            },
            {
              'Build' => '135',
              'Release' => '11.0'
            },
            {
              'Release' => '12.0',
              'Build' => '133'
            },
      
            {
              'Build' => '115',
              'Release' => '11.0'
            }
            
          ]; `

Comment: FYI, there are duplicated `{ 'Release' => '11.0', 'Build' => '135' }` , so i'm thinking of removing the second `{ 'Release' => '11.0', 'Build' => '135' }` and just keep the first one.

Comment: Your code has imbalanced braces. Is this a complete subroutine?

Answer (score 0):

So I would create a new array for the stripped down list, and a hash to keep track of what you've seen:

```
my ( @trimlist, %trimkeys ) ;
for ( @$json_releasebuild_array )
{
  my $kval= "r$_->{Release}b$_->{Build}" ;  # make a unique string for each entry
  next if exists $trimkeys{$kval} ;
  push @trimlist, $_ ;
  $trimkeys{$kval}= 1 ;
}

$json_releasebuild_array= \@trimlist ;
```